# Тэги структур в Go

Tags: json, golang, сериализация

В Go при сериализации JSON в структуру используются "мета-теги", которые записываются рядом с полями структуры:

```
type Response2 struct {
    Page   int      `json:"page"`
    Fruits []string `json:"fruits"`
}
```

В данном случае это:

```
`json:"page"`
```

и

```
`json:"fruits"`
```

Но иногда, вместо JSON используются другие стандарты, BSON и др. Мой вопрос заключается в том, как использовать пользовательские типы? Можно в комментариях привести ссылку на документацию, где пишется об этом. До текущего момента я не смог найти упоминания о custom-конструкциях этого вида.

Второй вопрос. Кроме экспорта из файлов, можно ли эти теги использовать для других целей. Если да, то каким образом и для чего?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

О тэгах структур почитать можно [здесь](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Struct_types):

> A field declaration may be followed by an optional string literal tag, which becomes an attribute for all the fields in the corresponding field declaration. An empty tag string is equivalent to an absent tag. The tags are made visible through a reflection interface and take part in type identity for structs but are otherwise ignored.

Любой пакет может достать их из типов через средства пакета [`reflect`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/). Пример, функция, которая печатает только те поля, которые отмечены тэгом `print:"yes"`:

```
func f(i interface{}) {
    v := reflect.ValueOf(i)
    t := v.Type()
    for i := 0; i < t.NumField(); i++ {
        f := t.Field(i)
        fv := v.Field(i)
        if f.Tag.Get("print") == "yes" {
            fmt.Println(fv.Interface())
        }
    }
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/dCQwqCL0Hh.

Comment: Указанную ссылку я, вероятно, просматривал сам. Но, увы, так и не понял, как и для чего делать мне кастомные теги

Comment: @hedgehogues На "для чего делать" можно ответить "для чего хотите". Тэги - это просто текст. Но что именно вам не понятно с "как делать"?

Comment: Примеры использования, помимо `encodig/json`. Я понимаю, что вопрос задан немного в холиварном стиле. Но, всё-таки, есть, вероятно, набор стандартных случаев, когда можно использовать теги

Comment: @hedgehogues Никто вас не останавливает от использования их как хотите. Есть только пожелания не превращать их в "мета-язык". Если хотите примеров, посмотрите [`encoding/xml`](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/xml/#Marshal), [`gopkg.in/go-playground/validator.v9`](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/go-playground/validator.v9), [`github.com/jmoiron/sqlx`](https://github.com/jmoiron/sqlx#usage).

Answer (score 5):

Для других библиотек используются другие теги. В теге может быть несколько полей для разных библиотек, например:

```
type Response2 struct {
    Page   int      `json:"page" yaml:"page" validation:"min:1,max:10"`
    Fruits []string `json:"fruits" yaml:"fruits,omitempty" validation:"nonempty"`
}

r := &Response2{}
json.Read("file.json", r)
validator.Validate(r)
yaml.Write("file.yaml", r)
```

Теги можно разбирать самому и использовать в своих библиотеках - https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#StructField

Comment: Есть ли пример того, как использовать эти теги в своём коде? Я не понимаю. Примеров найти не могу. Речь веду именно о кастомных тегах